# Raspberry Pi to Arduino Continuous Serial Communication

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I want to send data from my Raspberry Pi to Arduino using the pyserial library from the side of Raspberry Pi. I just used a USB to connect the two devices. First I uploaded a program to the Arduino that checks if there is an available serial data then I am going to read it and compare the received data using if else statements. It works properly if I set the delay between writing to the serial port every 5 seconds in the Python program but if I set the delay to 1 second, it reads it at random times. I just use Windows for now to test it before I run on it on the Raspberry Pi. Is there any way I can make the sending of data faster rather than adding a 5 seconds delay? Below is the sample code I wrote.

Python

```
import serial
import time

port=serial.Serial('COM8',9600)
time.sleep(5)

try:

    while True:
        port.write(b'Hi\n')
        time.sleep(5)
except:
    port.close()
```

Arduino

```
String dataIn;
int led = 13;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);

  Serial.flush();
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    dataIn = Serial.readStringUntil("\n");

    if (dataIn == "Hi\n")
    {
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);
      delay(1000);
    }

    Serial.flush();
    dataIn = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: It takes more than 2 seconds each loop in Arduino's program, so if you send data every second some of the data will be lost. Then you will actually receive data every 2~3 seconds.

Comment: I changed the Arduino code in such a way that it will print the data received in a LCD. No delays anymore. Then in Python program, I changed `time.sleep(5)` to `time.sleep(1)`. On the first run, the output of LCD is "Hi" after sometime it does able to receive the data. Then after some random times, it prints "HiHiHi" or any string that contains multiple "Hi". What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Try connect one of your board to your PC,use a serial debug tool to see which one's fault it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using String lib like the one below

```c
  String command;


  void loop() { 
  if (Serial.available()) 
  {
    command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    command.trim();
    command.equals("something");
    /*your Implementation here*/
  }
}
```

it works well for me